# How to explore adjacent areas with maximal possible continuous length for the zero-element in matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have the matrix:

```
5 5 1 4 4
4 0 2 4 2
5 0 0 2 0
5 4 3 0 1
1 3 3 2 1
```

As you can see the matrix has the areas with zeros. For the stairs-like zero's area (look at cooordinates `(1, 1)(2, 1)(2, 2)`. This are is enclosed by

- `0` areas with digit `1`
- `1` areas with digit `2`
- `1` areas with digit `3`
- `2` areas with digit `4`
- `2` areas with digit `5`

The main point is that digit-area can be continuous if a neighbor element has the same value.

For example look at the nearest `5` to the zero area on coordinate `(0, 1)`. It has the neighbor with coordinate `(0, 0)`. Also the second `5` area is placed from the `(2, 0)` coordinate has the neighbor `(3, 0)`. So, totally, we have two `5` areas with coordinates `(0, 1), (0, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)` and, so, the length of `5`-area for **this** zero-area is `4`!

The `3` are has a length `3` (it starts from `(3, 2)` and goes to `(4, 2)` and then to `(4, 1)`. The point is to replace elements of zero-area (i.e. all zeroes within) on values in range `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` where corresponding digit-area has the biggest length. In our case all zeroes are replaced on `5`. The same thing is made with other zero-areas.

**The question is what an algorithm should I use?** The only idea that came to my mind was to create some huge map-dictionary and somehow look up intersections of coordinates and change states, but it was wrong. I have no more idea how to solve this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach

- First, use either DFS or BFS to identify continuous areas with the same digits. This can be done by

  - Visit each cell (in any order, e.g. top to bottom, left to right)
  - If the visited cell has not been marked as belonging to known continuous areas, run DFS or BFS starting from that cell and connect to neighbour cells that have the digits, then mark all the cell visited by DFS/BFS as a new areas
  - If the visited cell has been marked, just continue to the next cell
- After finishing all the DFS/BFS, you will have a map from each cell to each unique areas. For instance, the areas will be segmented as below (I will use alphabets to mark areas to avoid confusion with the digits, but in the actual, you can use integer numbers to mark the areas as well)

```
a a b c c
d e f g h
i e e j k
i l m n o
p m m q o
```

- You should also calculate the length of each area: `area_len = {a: 2, b: 1, c: 2, etc...}`, and the set of areas associated with 0: `zero_areas = {e, k, n}`
- Next, you need to construct the set of neighbour areas of zeros associated with each digits: `D[i] = set of neighour of zeros associated with digits i`. For instance, `D[5] = {a, i}, D[1] = {o}`.

  - This can be done by looping over all cells in zero areas and looking at all the neighbours of such cells

```
for area in zero_areas:
   for cell in area:
      for neighbour_cell in neighbours of cell:
          add area of neighbour_cell to D[digit of neighbour_cell]
```

- Lastly, for each digit `i`, calculate the sum of the area length in `D[i]` and choose the largest one.

Time complexity = complexity of DFS/BFS + size of zero-areas = O(M) with M being the number of elements in the matrix = O(N^2) with N being the rows and columns of the matrix

Comment: Good one! Thank you